# Searching on a remote GeoNetwork catalogue

Tags: geonetwork, search, catalog-service

On a GeoNetwork 3.0 node, I would like to search directly on another remote GeoNetwork node rather then harvest its data.

My goal is to incorporate search results from the remote node and the local node into one single response.

I can search on a local catalogue using the `q`-search service from the API.

In the [docs](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/developer/xml_services/metadata_xml_search_retrieve.html) from version 2.10 I found the hint, that there is an option `remote`, which should be used for searching on remote GeoNetwork catalogues when using the `xml.search` service.

I wonder, if this can be applied for the `q`-search service in the 3.x version. Is there any example how to achieve this or has anyone done something similar before?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options, that I currently see for this issue:

- Enhancing the local catalog instance according to this [document](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/advanced-configuration/#advanced-configuration-for-larger-catalogs), so there is more space for additional datasets and the second (remote) node is not needed.
- Using CSW endpoint which has the distributed search methodology already in the specification. Using the additional parameters `DistributedSearch` and `hopCount` in an KVP query should allow exactly this. I didn't test this yet. For reference, see table `KVP encoding for GetRecords operation request` in the CSW 2.0.2 implementation specification, which you can get from [here](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat#downloads).